# javascript show the source of page the that runs the script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a firefox extension, and I would like to know how can I see witch file my script is running on.
I'm using `window.location.href` but in my case is not so useful.
Because I want to know what kind of file, for example, i just want my script be run on html files.

How can I do this? some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (document.doctype) {
        if (document.doctype.name == 'html') {
```

easy :)
thank you anyway for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an Error, catch it and inspect the callstack.

```
var frames = [];
try {
    throw new Error("debug");
} catch (exception) {
    if (exception.stack && typeof exception.stack === "string") {
        var lines = exception.stack.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 1) {
            var frame = lines[i].match(new RegExp("^(.*)@(.*):(.*)$"));
            frames.push({
                "function": frame[1] || "anonymous",
                "line": frame[3],
                "file": frame[2]
            });
        }
    }
}
console.log(frames);
```

Comment: error on if exception is not defined. i dont understand so much about exceptions

Comment: `e` should be `exception`, sorry.

Comment: what e? exception should be e?